# What overcomes “DR 15/cold iron and magic”?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage-reduction

A friend showed me a [wendigo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/wendigo) and there was something in its entry that left me confused.

> DR 15/cold iron and magic;

Now to overcome the DR / Magic could be done by any magic weapon or spell as in [overcoming DR](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Overcoming-DR).

> magic weapons (any weapon with a +1 or higher enhancement bonus, not counting the enhancement from masterwork quality)

To overcome cold iron would require either a weapon made from cold iron or a +3 enhancement. The

> Weapons with an enhancement bonus of +3 or greater can ignore some types of damage reduction, regardless of their actual material or alignment.

So my understanding is that because there are multiple components to the DR each must be met. So to overcome the listed DR for the wendigo could be done by using a +3 weapon or by using a +1 cold iron weapon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are correct, yes. Ordinarily, DR 15/cold-iron-and-magic requires that a weapon be both magic and cold iron to bypass it, but a +3 weapon counts as cold iron (and silver) for the purposes of DR, and it’s obviously magic, so it would bypass the DR as well.

Comment: Where can I find this information that a +3 weapon counts as silver and cold iron?

Comment: @Azrael: [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Damage-Reduction)

Comment: I suspect very few people will have a cold iron weapon that isn't also magic.

Comment: @Clearer - lot's of people carry secondary cold iron weapons if they have other primary material intentions or just can't afford the enhancement extra cost. Cold iron dagger. Silver battle aspergillm (with a hollow handle with a vial of holy water in the handle, just in case). Easy ways to contribute without breaking the bank.

Comment: @Julix Bear in mind that that is a *strictly* low-ish-level tactic. By mid levels, switching to a mundane, or mildly-magical, back-up weapon *doesn’t* contribute much of anything, because of the demands that are placed on warriors having powerfully-magical weapons at those levels.

Comment: haha, fair point... DR15 isn't common at low levels... -- oh, and I forgot the word "Equivalent" (thust +1 quality a quality b is same as +3 for beating DR), which helps a lot.